# This plugin is not supported

Tags: html, object, types, innerhtml

When the following javascript is executed on Chrome (version 55), it reports "This plugin is not supported." Since it works on all other browsers, I would like to know the workaround for Chrome:

```
windowload = function($loadblog) {
var eheight = (window.innerHeight) - 120;
loader = "<object type='type/html' data='" + $loadblog + "' ";
loader+= "style='height: " + eheight.toString() + "px; ";
loader+= "width:800px;' onContextMenu='return false'></object>";
document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = loader; }
```

Comment: That probably depends on what's in `$loadblog`. Presumably you're trying to load a plugin from somewhere that Chrome either blocks, or doesn't have a handler for. What are you trying to load?

Comment: What this process does is it loads an htm file into an element on the web page (in this instance, "blog" is a span element.